# SQL to identify duplicates in a tree-like structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a solution for this (MS SQL 2008, btw):

`ID   |  ParentID  | Feature_1  |  Feature_2
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
  1   |     NULL   |         A  |          B
  2   |        1   |         A  |          B
  3   |        1   |         A  |          C
  4   |        2   |         A  |          C`

Whenever a child (a record with a ParentID) has the same set of features (Feature_1 and Feature_2) than its parent, I want to ignore it, essentially not show it in my select *.

So the result set should be

`ID   |  ParentID  | Feature_1  |  Feature_2
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
  1   |     NULL   |         A  |          B
  3   |        1   |         A  |          C
  4   |        2   |         A  |          C`

Note that ID=2 is dropped, but ID=4 is displayed because it has a different set of features than its parent had.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks guys, but I gave a bad example. A parent can have multiple entries, as well as its children. All of those need to be checked for duplicates, or essentially be grouped so I only see unique Feature-combinations for a parent and all of its direct child (regardless how many records there are). So effectively I need to compare sets.

Comment: Then in you example you would want to keep the record with ID 2 since it is a unique parent?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Child.ID,
    Child.ParentID,
    Child.Feature_1,
    Child.Feature_2
FROM
    MyTable AS Child
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS Parent
        ON Child.ParentID = Parent.ID
WHERE
    Parent.Feature_1 <> Child.Feature_1
    OR Parent.Feature_2 <> Child.Feature_2
    OR Child.ParentID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    Child.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table A
WHERE a.ParentID IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM table b
                 WHERE a.ParentID = b.ID
                 AND a.Feature_1 = b.Feature_1 AND a.Feature_2 = b.Feature_2)
```